# Displaying the product image on the downloads tab of woocommerce's account page

Tags: woocommerce, download, account

I'm trying to hack the woocommerce account page so that it shows the product's image on the downloads tab instead of just a table/list.

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

The best would be if it could look something like this, but I would like to at least show the image in the table:

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for the answer to this question as well. Ironic it was just asked today. This functionality should be part of core for downloads, products in the order view, checkout etc.